# Loading a CSV File taking forever

Tags: matlab, ram

I am trying to load a 4.0 GB large CSV file into Matlab. I have 40GB of RAM. However, the table does not seem to finish loading. (Activity Monitor showed fast increase of RAM use up to 38.64GB and stopped after that. CPU still in heavily in use.)
According to the force quit menu of apple, matlab is has not gotten stuck. (I'd guess a missing "Matlab is not responding"-message signals that.)

1st Question: Why does it even take up that much RAM? I've read RAM duplicates. Can I do something in this regard?

2nd Question: Can I speed this project up. Split the CSV somehow?

3rd Question: Can I speed up my computer? It is taking forever, while using only 30% of CPU capacity... Why does it not use more? The vents are not crazy loud, so I guess "it's chilling".

Edit: It went up to 72.80 and is now decreasing... 
Edit: Now back down at 55.something

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you running?

Comment: @FranzWurst 2018b (9.5.0.94444)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few concepts you should be aware of with Matlab.

1. Strings are stored as UINT16 (sort of, I can never get this right). Importantly what this means is that every character requires 2 bytes. If you stored the entire file as a long string it would take up 8 GB.
2. Values, whether they are arrays or scalars, are stored with headers. This means that storing a string (technically a character array, strings - the ones with double quotes instead of single quotes - may be different) requires a header that is roughly 104 bytes. This means something like 'test' requires roughly 108 bytes! If you can store an array of numbers then the 104 byte overhead is minimal. If you have a cell array of scalars, then each scalar is taking up 112 byes (assuming the scalar is an 8 byte double). This might be a bit confusing but in the end it means if you're not careful reading a CSV file your memory requirements can explode.

So what can you do. Tables store columns as arrays where possible. You can try `readtable` although I think the underlying implementation might not be memory efficient.

For large files Matlab suggests using the `datastore` function. It will fix your memory problem although it may be a bit slow.

The other option is to read the entire file into memory and to do your own custom processing. For example, assuming you don't have anything escaped (i.e. commas that are not actually delimiters), you can find all relevant delimiters by using:

```
%Find comma or newline
I = regexp(temp,',|\n')
```

Here's an example of extracting various columns. As indicated above, this has a large overhead for strings (character arrays) but is efficient for numbers.

```
%Fake data as an example, 3 columns with middle one numeric
temp = sprintf('asdf,1234,temp\nfred,324,chip\ncheese,12,you are always right');
I = regexp(temp,',|\n');
starts = [0 I];
ends = [I length(temp)+1];

n_columns = 3;
%extract column 2
c2 = arrayfun(@(x,y) str2double(temp(x+1:y-1)),starts(2:n_columns:end),ends(2:n_columns:end));

%extract column 1
c1 = arrayfun(@(x,y) temp(x+1:y-1),...
    starts(1:n_columns:end),ends(1:n_columns:end),'un',0);
```

Depending on your use case this may work or it may not. To read the file into memory you can use `fileread`

Answer (score 0):

I think that MatLab itself has a limit of how much input it is allowed to take in. I'm sure you can set that in the preferences if you have the high enough version.

Check this out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/set-workspace-and-variable-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

In answer to question(2): It is quite straightforward to split the csv up, assuming there are more rows than columns...

```
bigfile= csvread(filename);
bigLen=length(bigfile);
size=unint64(bliglen/2)
csvwrite('first.csv', bigfile(1:size,:));
csvwrite('second.csv', bigfile(size:beglen,:));
```

Or even doing this with SEVERAL files; it may not make it faster overall, but it would allow you to observe the process as each file is read.